# ¿cómo puedo crear una cookie en django cuando hago click en un botón?

Tags: django, cookies

Tengo un template para ver el detalle de un producto, adicional en ese mismo template tengo un `partial`

```
{% include 'products/plans_list.html' %}
```

Donde estoy listando todos los planes que estan disponibles para ese producto.

Quiero que cuando se seleccione un plan, dando click en el botón *reserva* se cree una cookie con el valor del id de ese plan y otra con el id del producto.

El boton ***reserva*** me lleva a otro template donde esta el detalle del plan:

```
<a href="{%url 'products:activityplans_detail' plan.id %}">RESERVA</a>
```

No sé como tomar el valor de `plan.id` ni de `producto.id` para crear las cookies. Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Tomar el valor, te refieres a esto {{plan.id}} {{producto.id}}

Comment: ya lo resolviste quiza ?

Comment: No lo he resuelto. Lamento si parece una copia de la otra pregunta, soy nueva en esto. Estoy probando enviar al diccionario del contexto el plan.id para pasarlo como valor
response.set_cookie('llave', plan.id)
Aunque sigue sin funcionarme.

Comment: Puedes añadir la función o view con la que intentas crear la cookie? Posiblemente esté ahí tu problema

Comment: Hola! ya pude resolverlo. Lo que hice fue pasar como elemento el id del plan en la url de la reserva:
`path('create-reservation/<int:id_plan>/', createReservationView.as_view(), name='createReservationView'),`

Luego con javascript recorto la url y tomo el id. No sé si sea la forma más elegante pero funciono :D